# linking OMOperatingUnit table to CompanyInfo in AX 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

My first table temporary return result of `companyInfo` and the second table temporary return result of `omoeratingUnit`
So i want to link the both table but i don't Know how can i do that .So for that i"m trying to test this query  but it return 0 record.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DIRPARTYTABLE Party
    INNER JOIN MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.DIRPARTYTABLE Common
        ON  Common.RECID = Party.RECID
        AND Common.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE = 2376

    LEFT OUTER JOIN MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.DIRPARTYTABLE  OMOPerating 
        ON  OMOPerating.RECID   = Common.RECID
        AND OMOPerating.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE = 2377
        AND OMOPerating.RECID   = Party.RECID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.DIRPARTYTABLE CompanyInfo 
        ON   CompanyInfo.RECID = Common.RECID
        AND  CompanyInfo.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE = 41
        AND  CompanyInfo.RECID  = Party.RECID
        AND  CompanyInfo.DATAAREA = 'USMF'
```

SO is there a relation between `CompanyInfo Table and OMOperatingUnit Table`

Any body help in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AX extended tables are saved in SQL as flatted of all extended tables.
So all `OMOperatingUnit fields` are in the same row in the `DirPartyTable` table.

One record/row can be only one of the types. You can not mix *CompanyInfo* **and** *OMOperatingUnit*.

[image: OMOperatingUnit]
[image: OMOperatingUnit - fields]

Comment: Exactly , i think the only way to link two table is to create an hierarchy in  `Administration d'organisation/Courant/Organisations/Hiérarchies de l'organisation` so for the companyinfo we can add the OMOperatingUnit